# PHP cURL get last Tweet

Tags: php, twitter, curl

I'm basically trying to get the last tweet on my Twitter page and echo it out, came across this code which ostensibly should do what I want but it gives me an error:

```
$user = 'TwitterUserName';
$pass = 'password';

$tweet = curl_init("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml");

curl_setopt($tweet, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);
curl_setopt($tweet, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$out = curl_exec($tweet);

$out = new SimpleXMLElement($out);

echo $out->status[0]->text;
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\twit.php:13 Stack trace: #0 H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\twit.php(13): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\twit.php on line 13
```

Any ideas on what's causing the error? Or any suggestions for a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML string that is being returned is invalid. Verify that the fetched string is actually XML (and valid!).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use basic auth for twitter's REST API, you have to use OAuth for their API. For some basic resources on twitter oauth: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api#oauth

Since you are using PHP, I'd suggest looking at abraham's oauth library, which was the first one to be widely used: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth But there are a number of very useable libraries out there for many different languages: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

And here's a good doc on transitioning from basic auth to oauth: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/moving-from-basic-auth-to-oauth

Aside form that, I believe JSON has become the wider used standard for API responses. As long as your version of PHP has all the JSON functions (>= 5.2.0, IIRC) then I'd change your url from *.xml to *.json.